# Displaying json results (from php) in html div (using Ajax with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I get json results from a php file and I want to append them to a specific div section in another php file using ajax with jQuery.For now I have to results..Please help me in this

json results:

```
[
{
    "title": "Welcome!",
    "description": "The world has changed dramatically..",
    "image": "img/article1.jpg"
},
{
    "title": "Welcome 2!",
    "description": "It is time for a new start..",
    "image": "img/article2.jpg"
}
]
```

And the jQuery I am using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
     url: 'ajax_json.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: {tag: 'getData'},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
            if(data.success){
                $.each(data, function(index, record){
                    if($.is_numeric(index)){
                        var row = 
                        $("#output").append('<div class="article"><div>' + item.title + '</div><div style="width:200px;height:100px;background-image: url(' + item.image + ')"></div></div>');
        });
                    }
                })
              }
            }
        });
    });
```

Div section:

```
<div class="row top-buffer" id="output">
       <div class="col-md-6" >
         <img class="img-rounded" src="json image" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">

          <h3>json title</h3>
          <p class="well">json description<p>
     </div>
```

Comment: where is your class="output"  in html

Comment: I just updated my code.It is the first time I am using AJAX so it is a little bit tricky for me now.

Comment: you are making so much mistake in a simple Ajax, you are appending `item.title`    where is item. if want rewrite all. ask ?

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand you.What is the wrong in the code?

Comment: OK, copy all inside #output div and paste it inside .append  Now you replace your json image, json title and json description to item.title , item.description etc... You should append inside #output. and remove `var row `

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008277/displaying-json-results-from-php-in-html-div-using-ajax-with-jquery#38008277

Answer (score 2):

**Html should be**

```
<div class="row top-buffer" id="output">


</div>
```

**Your JS should be**

```
var json_ = {
    "0": {
        "title": "Welcome!",
        "description": "The world has changed dramatically..",
        "image": "img\/article1.jpg"
    },
    "1": {
        "title": "Welcome 2!",
        "description": "It is time for a new start..",
        "image": "img\/article2.jpg"
    },
    "success": "true"
};

if (json_.success){  
    $.each(json_, function (index, item) {
        if ('success'!= index){
 $('#output').append("<div class='col-md-6' ><img class='img-rounded' src="+item.image+"alt='MyImage' width='550px' height='240px'></div><div class='col-md-6'><h3>"+item.title+"</h3><p class='well'>"+item.description+"<p></div>");

        }
    });
};
```

Check result Here : http://codepen.io/ihemant360/pen/BzpKew

You are using external php file so your code should be :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
     url: 'ajax_json.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: {tag: 'getData'},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
            if(data.success){
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            if ('success'!= index){
     $('#output').append("<div class='col-md-6' ><img class='img-rounded' src="+item.image+"alt='MyImage' width='550px' height='240px'></div><div class='col-md-6'><h3>"+item.title+"</h3><p class='well'>"+item.description+"<p></div>");
                });
              }
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: Any ideas how can I remove these `[ ]` from json format?

Comment: this is json array. learn syntax here : [JSON Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 1):

lost of small errors you have

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/06b0r8cj/)

**fixed html code:**

```
<div class="row top-buffer" id="output">
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <img class="img-rounded" src="json image" alt="MyImage" width="550px" height="240px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <h3>json title</h3>
        <p class="well">json description<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fixed js code :**

```
if (data.success){  
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        if ('success'!= index){
                $("#output").append('<div class="article">1<div>' + item.title + '</div><div style="width:200px;height:100px;background-image: url(' + item.image + ')"></div></div>');
        }
    });
};
```

The main error is there:

```
 $.each(data, function(index, record){
//item is in record var but then you are trying to use item var
$("#output").append('<div class="article">1<div>' + item.title + '</div><div style="width:200px;height:100px;background-image: url(' + item.image + ')"></div></div>');
```

hope it will help =)

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting json as string from server.

Try using before your if condition and use articleData for processing -

```
var articleData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Also, it should be record.title instead of item.title.